# Is there any command to create a db copy from another db MySQL

Tags: mysql

is it possible to create a copy from another db using commant in mysql without using sql file

I tried this command

```
mysqldump -u username -p old_database | mysql -u username -p new_database
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
lakhendrakushwah@LAKHENDRAs-MacBook-Air ~ % sudo -s 
Password:
root@LAKHENDRAs-MacBook-Air ~ # mysqldump -u root -p lakha | mysql -u root -p testDB
Enter password: Enter password: 
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
root@LAKHENDRAs-MacBook-Air ~ # mysqldump -u root -p lakha | mysql -u root -p testDB
Enter password: Enter password: 
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
madhu@cool

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but you will have to provide the password in the same command.

`ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`: The error is due to password not specified in the command itself.

Give it a try!

```
mysqldump -u username -p'your_password' old_database | mysql -u username -p'your_password' new_database
```

***Note:** new_database must be created first using CREATE DATABASE if not present already.